# Spring Data JPA Specification With Projection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, projection, specifications

I am trying to use Specification with Projection but I get an error:
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [com.entity.ParticipationEntity] to type [com.entity.TenantOnly]

Following is the projection :

```
public interface TenantOnly {
    String getTenantId();
}
```

My repository method is:

```
List<TenantOnly> tenantOnlies = participationSpringDataRepository.findAll(
                Specification.where(tenantIdIn(tenantIds)));
```

and participationSpringDataRepository extends JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
public interface ParticipationSpringDataRepository extends JpaRepository<ParticipationEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<ParticipationEntity> {
```

build version is:
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5
org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0

I tried invoking the repository using findBy:

```
public List<String> getParticipatingTenants(List<String> tenantIds,  List<String> programIds, OffsetDateTime processedDate){
    List<TenantOnly> tenantOnlies = participationSpringDataRepository.findBy(Specification.where(tenantIdIn(tenantIds)),
                q -> q.as(TenantOnly.class).all());

    return tenantOnlies.stream().map(tenantOnly -> tenantOnly.getTenantId()).toList();
}
```

But the select query has all the columns.
How do I select only the columns mentioned in projection and its distinct values?

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution :

[1] Ensure that your projection interface, TenantOnly, is in the same package (or a subpackage) as your repository interface. This is because Spring Data JPA looks for projection interfaces in the same package or subpackages of the repository interface.

[2] Check that you have the necessary dependencies in your project's build file (e.g., pom.xml for Maven or build.gradle for Gradle) to support Spring Data JPA and its converters. Make sure you have the appropriate versions of Spring Data JPA dependencies specified.

[3] Verify that you have a suitable implementation for JpaSpecificationExecutor available in your classpath. In your case, since you're extending JpaSpecificationExecutor in your repository interface, ensure that you have the appropriate JPA implementation (e.g., Hibernate) configured in your project dependencies.

[4] If you're using any custom converters in your application, make sure they are properly registered with Spring Data JPA's ConversionService or through @Converter annotations.

[5] If none of the above solutions work, you can try explicitly specifying the projection type using the @Projection annotation on your repository method. Modify your repository method as follows:

> @Projection(name = "tenantOnly", types = { ParticipationEntity.class
> }) interface TenantOnlyProjection {
> String getTenantId(); }
>
> List tenantOnlies =
> participationSpringDataRepository.findAll(Specification.where(tenantIdIn(tenantIds)), TenantOnlyProjection.class);

This explicitly tells Spring Data JPA to use the TenantOnlyProjection as the projection type for the query.

Comment: Hi, I have ensured that the projection interface is in a subpackage. The current structure is com.persistence.repo for ParticipationSpringDataRepository, com.persistence.entity for ParticipationEntity and com.persistence.view for TenantOnly

Spring data version org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.5. It has hibernate org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.7.Final

There are no custom converters. 

The problem is that the select query that is getting generated has all the columns and is not considering the columns mentioned in the projection interface

Comment: I tried invoking the repository using findBy: 

```
public List<String> getParticipatingTenants(List<String> tenantIds,  List<String> programIds, OffsetDateTime processedDate){
    List<TenantOnly> tenantOnlies = participationSpringDataRepository.findBy(Specification.where(tenantIdIn(tenantIds)),
                q -> q.as(TenantOnly.class).all());

    return tenantOnlies.stream().map(tenantOnly -> tenantOnly.getTenantId()).toList();
}
```

But the select query has all the columns. 
How do I select only the columns mentioned in projection and its distinct values?

Comment: I looked at the classes FetchableFluentQueryByPredicate and FetchableFluentQueryBySpecification. Both of them add the properties in the hint and not the select part of the query, and the postgres driver probably is not honouring it.

I am using postgres solution provided by aws and as per documentation hints are not supported:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/oracle-to-aurora-postgresql-migration-playbook/chap-oracle-aurora-pg.tuning.hints.html

Is there any way to get solve this problem

Comment: @NidhiKaushal Without checking complete code can't find proper solution, So if there is complete code after check whole code and then we can try to find better solution easily.